# How to validate datatype for a csv file in angular and set the minimum and maximum rows?

Tags: angular, typescript, csv

I'm trying to validate a CSV file that I'm uploading to ensure that it meets the requirements of a template. How do I go about setting the datatypes for each row and column along with setting a minimum and maximum row number in angular.

For example:
Column 1 - Name - John Doe needs to be validated to allow only string
Column 2 - Age - 30 needs to be validated to allow only integers